# Issue with an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some issues with an accidental infinite loop. I've just been starting with javascript, and so I've been trying to make a simple game as practice. I keep getting an infinite loop, and I can't tell why. I'm fairly sure it's not a syntax error, since the console isn't telling me about any. Here's the code where the problems are happening:

HTML:

```
<input id="lemonadePrice" class="buytextbox" placeholder="Lemonade price">
<input class="submit" onclick="begin();" type="submit" value="Begin!">
```

JavaScript:

```
while (isNaN(lemonadePrice)) {
    document.getElementById("introduction").innerHTML="Uh-oh! Your lemonade price is not a
number!Please remove any words or symbols like '$'.";
    lemonadePrice = document.getElementById("lemonadePrice");
}
```

Here's a link to the full code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shbababa/Pxuey/)

Comment: I don't think you understand what a while loop does...

Comment: @jraede what should I use instead then

Comment: Not sure why you have a `while`-loop. Instead of having the loop, just do the validation when the key is press.

Comment: Your loop would work only with synchronous input (e.g. `prompt()`), however inputting a value into an input element is an asynchronous action from the user.

Comment: I'm not a JScript expert, but I'm quite certain `document.getElementById("lemonadePrice")` returns the DOM element, **not** the value entered by the user, so `lemonadePrice` will never be a number, hence the infinite loop. (someone correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because of your `while()` loop. What might be happening is that the while loop goes on infinitely while this `isNAN(lemonadePrice)` returns `true`, and this is what happens in your case, given that you say it runs infinitely.

You can try using an `if()`.  Since .`getElementById` of "lemonadePrice" will not be returning a number, the `isNAN()` would be evaluating to true all the time. isNAN() simply means "is not a number". If you think for a second, you know where the bug is.

I think you are looking to get the value of "lemonadePrice", so instead of just getting the element, you should also consider pulling in the value that lies inside it. I do not see this in your code but it would simply be this DOM: `var value = document.getElementById(id).value;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an `if` instead of `while`

The definition while taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop)

> In most computer programming languages, a while loop is a control flow
>   statement that allows code to be executed repeatedly based on a given
>   boolean condition. The while loop can be thought of as a repeating if
>   statement.

It means while loop will repeat under condition that inside the brackets. In this case, what you need is a conditional statement (`if()`)

If will be executed only once. While will be executed repeatedly until the condition is false. In your case, the condition will be always true. That is why you ended up in infinite loop.

See code below

```
if (isNaN(lemonadePrice)) {
   document.getElementById("introduction").innerHTML="Uh-oh! Your lemonade price is not a
   number!Please remove any words or symbols like '$'.";
   lemonadePrice = document.getElementById("lemonadePrice");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume `begin()` is basically this:

```
function begin(){
    var lemonadePrice = document.getElementById("lemonadePrice");
    while (isNaN(lemonadePrice)) {
        document.getElementById("introduction").innerHTML="Uh-oh! Your lemonade price is not a number!Please remove any words or symbols like '$'.";
        lemonadePrice = document.getElementById("lemonadePrice");
    }
}
```

then your loop will never have a chance to exit, since `lemonadePrice` is always set to the "value" of the lemonadePrice DOM element; that means `lemonadePrice` will **always** be NaN, so the loop is infinite. Like others have already mentioned, you need to use an `if()` statment instead of a loop, and remove the last line. You also want to look at the **value** of the element:

```
function begin(){
    var lemonadePrice = document.getElementById("lemonadePrice").value;
    if(isNaN(lemonadePrice)) {
        document.getElementById("introduction").innerHTML="Uh-oh! Your lemonade price is not a number!Please remove any words or symbols like '$'.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use `onsubmit` and prevent form submit if not valid.
Its also better to use regular expression to check if its valid float number.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="yourfile.php" method="post" onsubmit="validate();">
    <input id="lemonadePrice" class="buytextbox" placeholder="Lemonade price" /> <span id="lemonade_error"></span>
    <br>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Begin!" />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
function validate() {
    var lemonade_price = document.getElementById("lemonadePrice").value;
    if (lemonade_price.match(/\d+\.*\d*/i)){
        document.getElementById("lemonade_error").innerHTML = "Not valid.";
        if (event.preventDefault){
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false; // for IE as dont support preventDefault;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
//]]>  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code here : http://jsfiddle.net/Pxuey/5/